# Android ListView with OnItemClickListener AND GestureDetector

Tags: android, listview, gesturedetector

I have a the following ListActivity:

```
public class ShowDayActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.day);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getListView().setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ...
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
        editEvent(pos);
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
        private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, 
                               float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
               return false;
            }
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.d("ICS-Calendar", "Fling left");
                return true;
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.d("ICS-Calendar", "Fling right");
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

The contextListener (long-click) on the listItems works perfectly. Today i added the gestureListener and Detector, which works too, BUT:

The GestureDetector detects a fling all right, but after it's done with its logic, the context menu opens, which is obviously not what i want. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong, or what i might do about it?

Answer (score 8):

Normally, you need to call *cancelLongPress()* method for view and all view's children after *onFling* has been detected. But for *AbsListView* this method do nothing :(

But I've found workaround for it: in the *onFling* callback, after all things were processed, do the next for your *ListView* object:

```
Event cancelEvent = Event.obtain(ev2);
cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
listView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
```

Comment: Cool. Alternative call if you don't have ev2:

list.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, 0, 0, 0));

Answer (score 6):

```
public class GestureDemoActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // something init code.
        getListView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                    cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    v.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```