# Disable "flinging" in android ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

When you have a `ScrollView` in android, you can scroll really fast by flinging the `ScrollView` up or down, but I don't want this enabled.

Is there a way to disable the flinging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to Override the `onFling()` method. Override the `onFling()` and just have it return false.

Here is an [EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817770/android-listview-with-onitemclicklistener-and-gesturedetector/) that might help you with creating a GestureDetector and overriding the `onFling()`.

---

For your `onFling()` method you will want this:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's actually `fling(int)` method to be overrided not `onFling()`, just override it with empty code or `super.fling(0)`, it works for me at API 16~21