# Xamarin.Android HorizontalScrollView, How to disable release momentum?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, scrollview

By default when I scroll the contents of scroll view and take off my finger the contents keep scrolling for a while after then stops. I want to know if there is a way to stop scrollview from keeping going after I take off my finger?

I'm using xamarin.android, tried [Disable "flinging" in android ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654883/disable-flinging-in-android-scrollview) solution but didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable "flinging" in android ScrollView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654883/disable-flinging-in-android-scrollview)

Comment: have no idea what is flinging, gotta try that one

Comment: Flinging is dragging the view and letting go, giving it momentum (which you want to disable).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654883/disable-flinging-in-android-scrollview didn't worked for me, updated my question